# Can't login Windows 2003 Standard

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2003

> To log on to this remote computer, you must be granted the Allow log on through Terminal Services right. By default, members of the Remote Desktop Users group have this right. If you are not a member of the Remote Desktop Users group or another group that has this right, or if the Remote Desktop User group does not have this right, you must be granted this right manually.

I am experiencing the above error on Windows 2003 locally on the server. It won't allow me to go further. It just doesn't let me log in. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657)

```
ntrights -u %USERDNSDOMAIN%\<username> +r SeInteractiveLogonRight
```

Comment: do i do this from the DOS. the server its a workstation not a domain server nor have any domain server on the network.

Comment: @IsaacOsianor http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657